# Скрипт который будет искать ответ в гугле

Tags: html, парсер, поиск-библиотек

Всем привет, у меня вопрос, возможно ли написать скрипт который будет искать ответы на вопрос в гугле?

Comment: да, можно .....

Comment: Где можно найти код для такого скрипта на js, только бесплатно?)

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютно бесплатно! :)

```
const link = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=';
let search = 'ответы на вопрос';
window.open(link + search, '_blank');
```